# Deploying two applications in GlassFish's root context

Tags: java, jsf, web, glassfish

I have two applications that I need to deploy to GlassFish and I'd like to know how to put the two in the same GlassFish root context. I know that to put an application in the root context, I need to write the following line in `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
 <context-root> / </ context-root>
```

So, when I acess `http://localhost:8080` this address will open my application. But how to deploy both in the root context? Will I have to change the port?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. 
Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your goal, but I don't think this is possible. If you access `http://localhost:8080`, which application would you want to be sent to? Would you expect GlassFish to guess which one you want and take you to a random choice? What's your desired outcome from a user's perspective?

Comment: What would be the point of this? How would glassfish pick one over the other?